# Django i18n particular behavior setup

Tags: python, django, internationalization, django-i18n

I need django i18n to work like this:
`site.com/lang/` set the session language to `lang`, writes it to the cookie and redirects user to `site.com`. If it's a first-time visitor and prefix is not specified, default lang is shown.

Sorry for such a basic question,example of urls.py and middlewares maybe would be extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Django comes with a pretty similar solution to what you are trying to do. It's called [The set_language Redirect view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/translation/#the-set-language-redirect-view). The difference is that it expects the language as a POST parameter. You might want to consider using this versus a custom solution.

If that's not what you're looking for, you could write your own Redirect View, that would set the language to `lang` and redirect to `site.com`

```
class SetLanguageView(RedirectView):
    url = reverse('home')

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super(self, SetLanguageView).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
        lang = kwargs.get('lang')
        if lang:
            # To set the language for this session
            request.session[settings.LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY] = lang
            # To set it as a cookie
            response.set_cookie(settings.LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME, lang,
                                max_age=settings.LANGUAGE_COOKIE_AGE,
                                path=settings.LANGUAGE_COOKIE_PATH,
                                domain=settings.LANGUAGE_COOKIE_DOMAIN)
        return response
```

And in `urls.py` you would have something like

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^(?P<lang>\w+)/$', RedirectView.as_view(), name='lang_redirect'),
```